# How to get a service bean inside a custom tag library class in Grails 3

Tags: java, groovy, grails3

I want to get a service bean from the application context inside my custom tag library. The service name i will get it from the custom tag attribute.

This is the code i previously used.

```
class CustomTagLib {
    static defaultEncodeAs = [taglib:'html']
    //static encodeAsForTags = [tagName: [taglib:'html'], otherTagName: [taglib:'none']]
    def selectList = { attrs ->
        try{
            String servName=attrs.service
            String servMethod=attrs.method
            ApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(session.getServletContext())
            def myservice=ctx."${servName}"

            attrs.from = myservice.invokeMethod(servMethod,null);
            out << g.select( attrs )
        }catch(Exception e){
            println("Exception in CustomTagLib in method selectList:"+e)
        }
    }
}
```

This code is worked me for Grails 2.3 version but not for version 3.
Please help me to find out a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
import grails.util.Holders

def myservice = Holders.getApplicationContext().getBean( servName )
```

Where servName would be your service name with lowercase first letter & camel case for the remainder

Comment: Working, i forgot about the letter case. Now the both are working, but the tag is showing in the front end as a string like `<select name="nameVal" ...`